# Hcitool whitelist command isn't working

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth-lowenergy, ubuntu-16.04, hci

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 dual boot windows. I am using a UD100 Bluetooth USB adapter (old computer isn't BLE compatible on its own!)

[I have a beacon that works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVm6i.png). `lescan` works ok (although seems to duplicate even without `--duplicates`). However, the `--whitelist` option doesn't seem to work at all.

[Terminal Output Image Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kadas.png)

As you can see from the above image, the whitelist feature fails to scan any beacons, and the `lewlsz` size never changes when I add a MAC address, even when trying different formats. Clearing the white list has no effect either.

Whats going on? I am trying to monitor multiple beacons, and writing scripts for this, and it would be nice to use `lescan --whitelist` and its  related `lewladd` and `lewlrm` commands instead of mucking about with egrep stuff such as `lescan | egrep 'MAC1|MAC2|...` for each MAC address I want to scan for.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the Bluetooth Device address of your peripheral a public or random static address? If it's a random, you need to add the option - -random to the lewladd command.

The lewlsz command returns the maximum number of devices that can be stored in the white list; not the current size.

Comment: Thank you for putting `--random` in context! I couldn't find the meaning of that option anywhere. My addresses must be random static because adding that worked, I am not sure why they are random static. I am retrieving these addresses straight from my nrf52 chips, so I assumed they would have been public. But that's a different question all together for a different forum.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: For anyone else curious and developing with nRF52 devices, [this forum post](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/question/43670/how-to-distinguish-between-random-and-public-gap-addresses/) explains why BLE addresses are random static.

Comment: To use a public address you need to purchase an address block. Nordic Semiconductor don't want to waste money so they have as default configuration that a static random address is used, that has been assigned in production. (If you wish you can purchase an address block and assign those addresses to your peripherals.)